# Nginx + Passenger suburi location

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

Phusion Passenger has a sample configuration for deploying a Ruby app under a suburi here: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/deploy/ruby/

The config so you don't have to click:

```
http {
    ...

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.phusion.nl;
        root /websites/phusion/public;
        passenger_enabled on;

        # This is the important bit
        location ~ ^/subpath(/.*|$) {
            alias /websites/secondapp/public$1;
            passenger_base_uri /subpath;
            passenger_app_root /websites/secondapp;
            passenger_document_root /websites/secondapp/public;
            passenger_enabled on;

        }
    }
}
```

However, when I build out something similar for my own application, this *also* seems to work fine:

```
location /subpath {
     alias /websites/secondapp/public;  
     passenger_base_uri /subpath;
     passenger_app_root /websites/secondapp;
     passenger_document_root /websites/secondapp/public;
     passenger_enabled on;

 }
```

I prefer the simpler configuration, and it seems to be working for me. It also lets me nest further location directives for things like IP white listing certain routes. Did I just make a time bomb where this will blow up on me way later?

Answer (score 0):

Time bomb went off - looks like I get to answer my own question the hard way.

We have an application serving `/` and several applications on sub routes like `/foo` and `/bar`.

The root application has an endpoint like `/foo_samples` which with this config gets served by the app under `/foo` instead of the root application.